# getting script is busy whle running scripts in firefox and seleniumrc

Tags: jquery, firefox, model-view-controller, selenium

I keep getting the following message even I have increased the default time out in browser.

This warning message:
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

I am running scripts against a MVC application and it gives message for every jquery script on the page.  Any idea how to fix this.

edit: If you run the application manually, it works fine. It just with the tests run using selenium cause a warning.

Comment: We don't have crystal balls, we can't tell without seeing the scripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium & Firefox: How can i turn off "Unresponsive script" warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233322/selenium-firefox-how-can-i-turn-off-unresponsive-script-warnings)